# Brownian motion nowhere differentiable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm reconstructing a proof that the Brownian Motion is nowhere differentiable. They chose $3$ points and because the increments are independent and $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1/n)$ they take instead a random variable $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The equality is
$$P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^3\{|W_{\frac{k+j}{n}}-W_{\frac{k+j-1}{n}}|\leq \frac{C}{n}\}\right)=\left[P\left(|Z|\leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]^3\leq \frac{C}{n^{3/2}}$$
Why is there a $\sqrt{n}$ in the middle and not an $n$?

Comment: What is the variance of $W_{\frac{k+j}{n}}-W_{\frac{k+j-1}{n}}$?  What is the variance of $Z$?

Comment: @GEdgar $1/n$ and $1$, so $n$ times bigger.

Comment: $W_t-W_s \sim \sqrt{t-s} W_1$